# Why printing document gives a different font result between windows 7 and linux ubuntu

Tags: javascript, windows, ubuntu

I have a print function using js print setup, everything is running well and works fine, but I have one problem that makes me confused. It was about the font style, when I print it on windows the font is correct like what I've set in the function print itself, but when I print it on linux (ubuntu) the font is not like what I've set before. What can I do to solve this problem? thanks in advance...

this is the function:

```
    function load(){
        var divElements = document.getElementById('areaCetak').innerHTML;
        //var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML =
                    "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" +
                    divElements +
                    "</body><style type='text/css' MEDIA='print'>@media print {.page-break{ display:block; page-break-after:always; } } body { color:#404040; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px;  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px ; } table { font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border-collapse: collapse; } th, td { padding: 0;  font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 10px; }</style>";

        //jsPrintSetup.setPrinter('EPSON LX-310 ESC/P'); //
        //jsPrintSetup.setPrinter('Epson-LX-300+-2');
        jsPrintSetup.getPrinter();
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('orientation', jsPrintSetup.kPortraitOrientation);

        //jsPrintSetup.setSilentPrint(1);
        //jsPrintSetup.printWindow(window);
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginTop', 0);
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginBottom', 0);
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginLeft', 0);
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginRight', 0);
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrLeft', '');
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrCenter', '');
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrRight', '');
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrLeft', '');
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrCenter', '');
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrRight', '');
        //jsPrintSetup.setSilentPrint(false);
        jsPrintSetup.clearSilentPrint();
        jsPrintSetup.setOption('printSilent', 1);
        jsPrintSetup.print();
    }
```

Comment: show us what you have done so far.

Comment: i have edited my question, hope u can help me... thanks.

Comment: Do you have the Arial font installed on your Ubuntu system?

Comment: different OS, different fonts, different renderers, different driver for display and print, even if those are same name, they are not always identical.

Comment: @YOU, thanks for your explanation, it makes me clearly understand what i was looking for. but is there any option that can I do to solve this problem since this project is used on windows and linux?

Comment: @duskwuff, the font is installed correctly.

Comment: Just do not use a Windows-specific font on a cross-platform project